# Center a container with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having trouble centering my containers with in IE (so the page content would be center). What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/FqW9d/11/

Comment: What version of IE? Looks ok to me in IE7 and 8.

Comment: Don't have that browser anywhere to test :( ..but your page should work fine, weird that its not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set a doctype, most typical reason for it not working in IE.  I wrote a blog about this a while ago: [margin: 0 auto; not centering in Internet Explorer?](http://www.endyourif.com/margin-0-auto-not-centering-in-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 0):

Works
margin: 0 auto; 
 ?
Work with absolute positions ?